# looping in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

My Table having columns like below

```
+-------------------+
|Percentage   Amount|
+-------------------+
|50           3000  |
|20           2000  |
|15           1500  |
|15           1500  |
+-------------------+
```

I want to update my amount of each row based on the **TotalAmount** i will pass in my procedure.

Example: If i give 50000 then it will re-calculate the amount based on the percentage in the table (3000 will update to 25000 like that...).

How to get the values of Percentage from each row and calculate the amount and update it?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_SAMPLE
(
    TOTAL_AMOUNT  NUMBER
)

AS

BEGIN
    UPDATE LOGIC...
END;
```

Comment: you should try something first...if it has any errors/problems, then negotiate

Comment: look up RATIO_TO_REPORT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by the simple UPDATE query:

```
update sample_table set amount = total_amount * percentage/100;
```

But if you need PLSQL loops you can use Cursor FOR LOOP :

```
for x in (select distinct percentage from sample_table) loop
  update sample_table set AMOUNT = total_amount * x.percentage/100 
  where percentage = x.percentage;
  dbms_output.put_line(x.percentage || ': ' || total_amount * x.percentage/100);
end loop;
```